# how to find the consecutive items in the list that are in a specific range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having the following python list [0.0, 5.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.30000000000000004] I'd like to return the count of the longest consecutive sequence of items less than 0.5

Expected result:
[0.0, 5.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.30000000000000004] should give an output of 2

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: What specifically poses a difficulty for you?  It's hard to address your problem if you don't say what you attempted, and why that failed.

Comment: I am able to output the number of items in the list that meet the required range. what troubles me is how to seperate the consecutive items from the others

Answer (score 0):

You can find the working sample down here:

```
list = [0.0, 5.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.30000000000000004]
listDict = {}

for idx, val in enumerate(list):
    for idx2, val2 in enumerate(list):
        if idx != idx2 and list[idx] != list[idx2] and abs(list[idx] - list[idx2]) < 0.5:
            listDict[str(list[idx])] = True
            listDict[str(list[idx2])] = True

print (len(listDict))
```

And this is [the link](http://ideone.com/kX3DVL) for the live sample.

Comment: @Jim this is Python 3 so why don't you give me an up-vote?

Answer (score 0):

Possible, but unstable approach:

```
def number_of_consecutive(data, min_threshold, max_threshold):

    sum_consec, max_value = 0,0

    for element in data:
        if element <= max_threshold and element >= min_threshold:
            sum_consec += 1
            if sum_consec > max_value:
                max_value = sum_consec
        else:
            sum_consec = 0
    return max_value
```

To find elements in range 0 to 0.5 for given list:

```
print number_of_consecutive([0.0, 5.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.30000000000000004], 0.0, 0.5)
"2"
```